# URLError: certificate verify failed during automated file download

Tags: python, https, ssl-certificate, urllib2, client-certificates

My code and the PEM version of my cert are not working to automatically log me into a site from which I need to download a file.  Can someone please help?!

I know that I'm using the correct client certificate, because I can download the file manually via Internet Explorer using the certificate.  Furthermore, my code for automating this task used to work.  What changed: I obtained an updated certificate which I now need to use.

The cert is provided to me in .pfx format.  In order to use the urllib.request.urlopen command in python 3.5, I need to convert it into .PEM file format.  Months ago when I first solved this issue, I could have sworn I performed that conversion with a built-in Windows utility.  However I cannot figure out how to do that again.  When in IE I select Tools >> Internet Options >> Content >> Certificates >> (select the cert) Export >> Next >> Yes, export the private key -- it does not allow me to export the file in Base-64 encoded X.509 (it's grayed out) which I understand uses PEM.  I need that private key.

So, my other option is to use the OpenSSL pkcs12 utility.  Here's the syntax:

```
OpenSSL> pkcs12 -in "C:\Users\Default\Documents\cert.pfx" -out "C:\Users\Default\Documents\cert.pem" -nodes
```

It generates the file, then in python:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from ssl import create_default_context
from shutil import copyfileobj

context = create_default_context()
context.load_cert_chain(r'C:\Users\Default\Documents\cert.pem')

with urlopen(url, context=context) as response, open(dl_path, 'wb') as out_file:
    copyfileobj(response, out_file)
```

Note: the url is identical to what I use in my web browser.  I receive the following errors:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:720)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:720)>
```

Upon inspection with notepad, the generated file looks very similar to the .PEM file for the old certificate.

I have done a lot of searching and tried to figure this out, but at this point, I don't know where to turn.  Can someone please help?!

Comment: What happens when you don't use a client certificate? Do you get the same error? I ask because that error message seems to suggest the server certificate is the one that can't be verified.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Hmmm...when I leave the "context" out of the urlopen call, I get the exact same error.  Which as an error message seems generally unhelpful.  The thing is, I know the server cert is working too...as I mentioned, I can connect to it manually when I use a browser.